# Decomposing tweet sentiment score in R

Tags: r, time-series, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to decompose the time series data of the twitter sentiment score in R.
Here is dput() of my twitter sentiment data after sentiment analysis.

```
dput(text_dfbtc$total_score)
c(-1, -2, 2, 2, -3, 2, 5, -5, -2, 2, 5, 1, 1, -2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
5, 1, 7, 3, 1, -6, 0, -1, 1, 3, -3, -12, -12, 1, -4, -18, 3, 
1, 4, .... 0, 0, -4)
```

There is a total of 3251 entries.

I use the following command to translate it into time series data:

```
ts_textdfbtc1 <- zoo(text_dfbtc$total_score, 
  order.by = seq(as.POSIXct("2022-09-18 00:00:00"), length=46019, by="min"))
```

46019 is the number of minutes between my starting and end point.
As my Twitter data returns tweets from every minute between two periods.

The following command head() of the time series data results into:

```
head(ts_textdfbtc1)

2022-09-18 00:00:00 2022-09-18 00:01:00 2022-09-18 00:02:00 2022-09-18 00:03:00 2022-09-18 00:04:00 2022-09-18 00:05:00 
                 -1                  -2                   2                   2                  -3                   2
```

However, when I use:

```
frequency(ts_textdfbtc1)

0.01666667
```

The error I eventually get for the decompose function is that my data has no or less than 2 periods. How can I correct for this? Or else, what am I overseeing or doing wrong?

Comment: I searched and tried several solution, none worked. Most of the solutions where based on different datasets(monhtly or weekly). Haven't found a solution for daily data(every minute/second and so on).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use POSIXct with `decompose` since `decompose` requires that the data be expressed in cycles.  That is, `decompose` assumes that a cycle is represented by 1 unit whereas POSIXct has a second as the unit.  Suppose we want a cycle to be 15 elements, i.e. 15 minutes in this case -- change the number to whatever a natural cycle should be ensuring that there are at least 2 full cycles in the data so if there are 40 points as in the Note at the end the largest cycle possible would be 20. With a cycle length of 15 the `ts` statement defining `tt` will generate times of 1+0/15, 1+1/15, 1+2/15 and so on. Fixing the input data shown in the question by removing the dot dot dot (see Note below) we have the following. No packages are used.  The X axis on the output of `plot` corresponds to `tt` and is in cycles, i.e. the first 15 points are the first cycle starting at 1.0, the second 15 points are the second cycle starting at 2.0 and so on.

```
tt <- ts(score, frequency = 15)
d <- decompose(tt)
plot(d)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
score <- c(-1, -2, 2, 2, -3, 2, 5, -5, -2, 2, 5, 1, 1, -2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
5, 1, 7, 3, 1, -6, 0, -1, 1, 3, -3, -12, -12, 1, -4, -18, 3, 
1, 4, 0, 0, -4)
```

Comment: Thank a lot!! This has helped me!!!